# Regular expression to match from start of line

Tags: python, regex

I want a python regular expression that matches all occurrences of `text` that appear on a line but only if `%` does not appear before `text`. For example, I want to match lines 1 and 2 below but not line 3:

```
1. some random stuff text and then something completely different
2. some random stuff text and % then something completely different
3. some random % stuff text and % then something completely different
```

I thought that this was easy as I just need to search from the beginning of the line for a character that is not `%`, or a newline charafter, and is followed by `text`. For reasons that I do not understand the following code:

```
import re
lines = '''1. some random stuff text and then something completely different
2. some random stuff text and % then something completely different
3. some random % stuff text and then something completely different
'''
re.findall('^[^%\n\r]*text')
```

finds only the match `1. some random stuff text` on the first line and not the match on the second line. On the other hand, `re.findall('[%\n\r]*text')` finds the three matches that you expect.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: your second line % ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the option `re.MULTILINE` to ensure that `^` matches on new lines.

```
import re
lines = '''1. some random stuff text and then something completely different
2. some random stuff text and % then something completely different
3. some random % stuff text and then something completely different
'''
result = re.findall('^[^%\n\r]*text', lines, re.MULTILINE)

print result
# prints: ['1. some random stuff text', '2. some random stuff text'
```